# How do you convert an arrayStack of Object into HashSet?

Tags: java

```
        public Set<Cell> solve(Maze maze) {

          ArrayStack<Cell> path = new ArrayStack<Cell>()

          return (Set<Cell>) path;
```

I'll keep it short, but I have made my maze solver and it works and it's stored in ArrayStack 'path' and I'm trying to convert it to a Set so I can return it but it isn't working and it's saying 'Unchecked cast'. Any suggestion on how I could fix this?

I tried iterating,

```
 HashSet<Cell> test = new HashSet<>();
    while(!path.isEmpty()) {
        marker.add(path.pop());
    }

    Iterator<Cell> itr = test.iterator();
    while(itr.hasNext()) {
        System.out.println(itr.next());
    }
```

It's not really showing how I wanted it to be even if it's reversed.

Comment: What does the definition of the `ArrayStack` class look like?

Comment: Your iterating approach is basically correct; what do you mean by "it's not really showing how I wanted it to be"?

Comment: Note: You're using `marker.add`, and never adding things to `test` set

Comment: HashSet does not preserve order and it doesn't allow duplicates by its nature. That might be why it's not displaying the way you expect.  If you want to preserve order then consider using a LinkedHashSet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are using the Apache `ArrayStack` class...

`ArrayStack` does not implement the `Set` interface so you cannot cast it to that type.

You need to create an instance of a `Set` implementation and populate it with the elements from the `ArrayStack`.  Note that the `Set` interface is specifically un-ordered.  If you want `Set` semantics but in a reliable order then consider using a `TreeSet` rather than a `HashSet`.  `TreeSet` implements `SortedSet` and will produce its elements in their natural ordering when iterated.  Since `ArrayStack` implements `Collection`, you should be able to do the following:

```
return new TreeSet<Cell>(path);
```

This assumes that `Cell` has a natural ordering that matches the position within the path.

Answer (score 0):

If it is `org.apache.commons.collections.ArrayStack`, you can create the set with

```java
return new HashSet<>(path);
```

Please note that a set can contain each object only once and the order of objects is not guaranteed. The "contain only once" is checked with `.equals()` (and `.hashcode()`) of the contained objects (so you might want to override those methods with a proper implementation for `Cell`).